How to get user data with PHP8 Google client + Javascript auth code
I have a working Vue application which log user in via Google Javascript SDK. This get a token/code (I really dont how they call it). Then I send this token to the PHP application which uses Google api php client but then I really dont know what to do. Documentation does not show which class or method to use. I tried something like this:
$this->google_client = new Client();
$this->google_client->setClientId(config('services.google')['client_id']);
$this->google_client->setClientSecret(config('services.google')['client_secret']);

//$this->google_client->setAccessToken($token);
$this->google_client->addScope('openid');
$this->google_client->addScope('email');
//$this->google_client->addScope('profile');
$access_token = $this->google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($token);

Log::info($access_token);

$this->google_client->setAccessToken($access_token);

But the Log store this:
[
  'error' => 'invalid_grant',
  'error_description' => 'Bad Request',
]  


Getting the token in the client side and then passing it to PHP seems like a slightly strange way to do things - any reason specifically you designed it like that? https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-web.md describes how to integrate with google authentication from PHP itself

There is nothing strange on this pattern. It simply does not do any strange redirects. Also this is API based application and it would be crazy to manage redirects in javascript.  Any suggestions ho to use this VALID token with Google php api?

I'm not sure if google supports it. You're trying to use a token generated by one client, on one machine, from another client running on another machine. If I was designing an API, that's the sort of thing which would sound like a security risk.

$access_token = $this->google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($token); - this method is used to exchange a code parameter for a token - a code parameter which you would get from implementing the redirect flow. Calling the setAccessToken method with the token you passed from the client side, is the correct way to go. What about that didn't work ...?

The problem was that this code comes from online application and it is ONE TIME code. So when I blocked the use of the code it pass through this error. Now I have another error - redirect uri mishmash which is weird cause I use same uri as the online app.
